# How do modern Operating Systems detect process starvation?

Tags: operating-systems, deadlocks

So first off do the modern operating systems like windows and linux have a method for detecting starvation? if not, why? and if they do, then how are they going to detect starvation of a process? (this was a question in our exam)

my take was this so correct me if this is not good or not possible:

i said we should implement a linked list of waiting processes (that are waiting for a resource or etc) then we periodically run a function(using interrupts) which checks this list and we have a variable for each process and we increase that everytime, when it reaches certain point then we would know its starving(but i still dont know how to know this "certain point")

so is this correct? if so then how can we know this "certain point"? ( I suppose one way is just look at the statistic of average waiting time of processes and do a little math?)

if not, what is your solution?

Comment: In the general case, I don't think we can detect we have reached the "certain point" and know there is starvation. You can detect deadlocks, sure. But if processes are still running there's always the chance they release their resources so to make other processes progress, and avoid their starvation.

Comment: A possible solution OS like windows 10,use a scheduling algorithm with priority queue that also uses the aging technique. Aging is a technique of gradually increasing the priority of processes that wait in the system for a long time.And this has been improving due to the effectiveness and efficiency of concurrency control updates.

Comment: @quintumnia but how is this aging  implemented?  how do operating systems increase the age of a processes ?  lets say we have n processes in the waiting queue, waiting for some resource to be free, how do we age them?

Comment: @chi so how the modern Operating systems detect starvations?

Comment: I don't think modern OSs detect them. At most, they can try to prevent them.

Comment: @chi but lets say a process gets starved in linux or windows, then for example if we are in the windows, wouldn't we get an error message saying the process is not responding? does starvation even happen in windows?  (if there is no problem in the code of the process itself)

Comment: That message simply means that the process stopped responding to OS "pings" for some seconds. This does not necessarily imply starvation -- maybe after 10 more seconds the process will become responsive again, but the OS can not know that. Also, it is possible that a process is starving (waiting for some semaphore) but it is still responding to OS "pings".

Comment: @chi so if in an exam they asked me how can we implement a way to detect if there is a process which is starving, what should i say?

Comment: @JohnP  ,let me assume that you want to implement process aging nor scheduling algorithm, Right?

Comment: @quintumnia well we can assume that our scheduling algorithm works fine and doesn't starve any process, and the starving could happen somewhere else (like because of semaphores and waiting for a resource etc), then in this case how can we detect it? (if we are going to use process aging, then how are we going to implement aging in this case?)

Answer (score -1):

Inline with @chi 's comment;  lets say process "x" gets starved in linux or windows, then for example if we are in the windows, wouldn't we get an error message saying the process "x" is not responding? Approximately no.

Now let's assume we want to detect process "x",before starvation nor aging;we have to read it's  arrival time, burst time,process id, priority from the text file and calculate the average waiting time and show the central processing unit utilization of each cycle,for instance;

Time 1 process X arrives

Time 2 process X runs

Time  3 process B arrives

Time 4 process X finishes..........,randomly.

Hope this can give you a little bit of insight.

Comment: But in the real life scenario we won't know the burst time of a process because we won't know how much time its going to need,  and we also don't know how long its gonna wait in queue, so how are we gonna calculate the average waiting time?